# Scheduling Web Audio Api playback, multiple plays issue

Tags: javascript, audio, web-audio-api

I am trying to schedule the beep sound to play 3x one second apart. However, the sound is only playing once. Any thoughts on why this might be? (It's included within a larger javascript funciton that declares context etc. . .)

```js
var beepBuffer;

var loadBeep = function() {  
 var getSound = new XMLHttpRequest(); // Load the Sound with XMLHttpRequest
 getSound.open("GET", "/static/music/chime.wav", true); // Path to Audio File
 getSound.responseType = "arraybuffer"; // Read as Binary Data
 getSound.onload = function() {
  context.decodeAudioData(getSound.response, function(buffer){
   beepBuffer = buffer; // Decode the Audio Data and Store it in a Variable
  });
 }
 getSound.send(); // Send the Request and Load the File
}

var playBeep = function() {
 for (var j = 0;j<3;j++) {
  var beeper = context.createBufferSource(); // Declare a New Sound
  beeper.buffer = beepBuffer; // Attatch our Audio Data as it's Buffer
  beeper.connect(context.destination);  // Link the Sound to the Output
  console.log(j);
  beeper.start(j); // Play the Sound Immediately
}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close - and the other answer's code will work - but it's not the synchronicity, it's that you're not asking context.current time to the start time.  Start() doesn't take an offset from "now" - it takes an absolute time.  Add context.currentTime to the start param, and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Your code assumes that `beeper.start(j)` is a synchronous method, i.e. it waits for the sound to complete playing. This is not the case, so your loop is probably playing all 3 instances at nearly the same exact time.

One solution is to delay the playing of each instance, by passing a time parameter to the `start()` method:

```
var numSecondsInBeep = 3;
for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    var beeper = context.createBufferSource(); // Declare a New Sound
    beeper.buffer = beepBuffer; // Attatch our Audio Data as it's Buffer
    beeper.connect(context.destination); // Link the Sound to the Output
    console.log(j);
    beeper.start(context.currentTime + j * numSecondsInBeep);
}
```

[See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/start) for more info on the `play()` API.